# Convert .pdf to xml in php

Tags: php

after googling a lot of time I still can not find a suitable answer how to convert .pdf to xml in php. Can some one help me to do this with some code or library?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe base64_encode it and put to XML to send wherever you want? Please note that base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php